# xml dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to read XML doc and show it in dropdownlist.In my XML i will have different user names and each will have one or more hobbies.Depending on the user I want to display their hobbies

```
<userid>Jean</userid>
<hobbies>Cycling</hobbies>
<hobbies>Reading</hobbies>....
 **more people***
```

something like what i have shown above A SINGLE USER MIGHT HAVE ONE OR MORE HOBBIES and when a user enters I must show only their hobbies on Dropdownlist ...what is the best way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 good solution. please check the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959257/populating-dropdown-from-the-xml-in-c-sharp)

this is the new way of doing it, it is called LINQ.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"Yourxmlfile.xml");
        var query = from xEle in xDoc.Descendants("publication")
                    select new ListItem(xEle.Element("name").Value, xEle.Attribute("tcmid").Value);

        ddlList.DataValueField = "value";
        ddlList.DataTextField = "text";
        ddlList.DataSource = query;
        ddlList.DataBind();
```