# Load XML into dropdown list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm new to XML and C#. I want to load a dropdown list with specific items from an XML-file. I want to fill it with all the persons where cityname=City1 (Person1, Person2, Person3 and Person4). The problem is that all the persons displays in the dropdownbox on one single row, instead of one person on each row.

Please help me

Here is my XML:

```
<country>
  <city>
    <cityname>City1</cityname>
    <citynr>111</citynr>
    <person>
      <name>Person1</name>
      <name>Person2</name>
      <name>Person3</name>
      <name>Person4</name>
    </person>
    <major>
      <firstname>Major1firstname</firstname>
      <lastname>Major1lastname</lastname>
    </major>
  </city>

  <city>
    <cityname>City2</cityname>
    <citynr>222</citynr>
    <person>
      <name>Person5</name>
      <name>Person6</name>
      <name>Person7</name>
      <name>Person8</name>
    </person>

    <major>
      <firstname>Major2firstname</firstname>
      <lastname>Major2firstname</lastname>
    </major>
  </city>
</country>
```

My code:

```
XElement country = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath("myXML.xml"));

XElement city = (
    from p in country.Elements("city")
    where p.Element("cityname").Value == "City1"
    select p
).First();                  

dropDownList.Items.Add(city.Element("person").Value);
```

Comment: try as this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959257/populating-dropdown-from-the-xml-in-c-sharp

Comment: Actually you are adding one item : dropDownList.Items.Add(city.Element("person").Value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation about XElement.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx):

> Gets or sets the **concatenated** text contents of this element.

What you should do according to your XML structure:

```
XElement persons = city.Element("person");
foreach (XElement person in persons.Elements("name"))
{
    dropDownList.Items.Add(person.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. What is the name persons in the second line?

Comment: Do you mean the variable named _persons_, or do you mean the string argument _"name"_?

Comment: I mean the persons as in persons.Elements("name")

Comment: @user2939293: Note the first line in my code snippet. There is the "birthplace" of the variable _persons_ ;)

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thanks a lot!